# mariadb create slave from another slave

Tags: replication, mariadb

I have a big database its like 800G, and I'm using MariaDB 10.2.9. My configuration is :

`Server A (master)
 Server B ( Slave from Server A)`

Now I setup `Server C` and I wanted that it reads everything from `Server B` not from `Server A`, I have already add these lines to my.cnf :

`log_slave_updates
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_format=MIXED`

but I don't know what should I do on `Server B` and `Server C` to do this solution.

Comment: please take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates although I would recommend to go with one master and two slave, unless you have a small site that need to have another slave in a different location

Answer (score 0):

Think back to how you set up B in the first place.  B will be the Master to Slave C.

It is rather unusually to chain 3 servers A->B->C instead of having 2 Slaves hanging of a single Master.  What is the ultimate goal?